# Url.Action call Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Url Action Link that sends to my controller 1 paramater, but I need that paramater to call a javascript function to get document.getElementById and send that value to my controller. In my view I have the follwoing code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.PersonsContacts as List<Software___FPPD.Models.Contact>)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ContactType.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.ContactValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "contactValue"} })</td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("EditPersonContact", "Person", new { contactValue = getValue(item.ContactValue)})" class="btn  btn-success">Alterar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My javascript:

```
function getValue(contactValue) {
    document.getElementById("contactValue").value = contactValue; 
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong because I can not get this to work.

Comment: Might be easier to use a for loop, not foreach, and reference the items with index. Then each ID will be unique. And contactValue can just equal PersonsContacts[x].ContactValue.

Comment: I need to use javascript for this. I'm working with a viewmodel that have multimodels. This part of the code is to change the values of a person in my contact table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Url.Action` is a method which gets executed in the server by razor and your javascript executes on the client side. So it is not that easy to mix both.

I am not sure what you are trying to do. In your question you mentioned you want to set value to some form field. But since you are going to be redirected to the new page, there is no point ! whatever value you set is gone (unless you are opening the new page in a new tab)

Anyway, What you can do is to listen for the `click` event of the anchor tag in your javascript and do whatever you want at the client side (ex: setting some form field value /executing a javascript function etc).

You have some problem in your view code, you are creating the same **id** value for each item in the loop in `@Html.EditorFor(model => item.ContactValue` .Duplicate id's are not valid. So avoid that.

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ContactValue,
                     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control myContactVal"} })
</td>
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("SignUp", "Home")"  data-contactvalue="@item.ContactValue" 
                                            class="btn  btn-success myEdit"> Alterar</a>
</td>
```

I added 2 new css classes , `myContactVal` and `myEdit` to the form fields to help us do our jQuery selection. We are setting the item.ContactValue value in html5 data attribute to the anchor tag for accessing later in our javascript  code.

And the javascript to handle the link click event

```
$(function () {

    $("a.myEdit").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        _this = $(this);
        var contactVal = _this.data("contactvalue");
        var url = _this.attr("href");
        url = url + "?contactValue=" + contactVal;
        alert(url);

        //You can do any other thing here.

        //If you want to update the field with  myContactVal class in prev td
        _this.closest("tr").find(".myContactVal").val(contactVal);


       // finally do the redirect 
        window.location.href=url;

    })

})
```

Comment: Hi What I am Trying to do is the following. I have a person that may have more than one contact. When I want to edit that person I have in my edit view a list of all that persons contact. In front of each contact I have a button that when we change the contact value we press that button and the ideia is to send to my controller the type of contact, it´s value and person Id and update my contact table.

Comment: You can set all those as html5 data attributes in your link and use those in the javascript to build the url

Comment: Your Ideia was great but when I change the contactvalue it sends to the function  type contact, the OLD contact value and person Id. Is it possible instead of reciving the old contact value,when I write a new contact value send that one. There rest is greate. Perfect

Comment: Where will you write ? In a textbox, if yes, you can the textbox value using jQuery(same as how we read the contactVal) and use that to append to your url.